# Deserializing a list of objects with different names in JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm getting my data from a website which returns a .json format that is quite unfamiliar to me. I've been looking for the solution for a couple of hours, and I must be using the terminology.

The json is formatted something like this:

```
[
{
    "Foo": {
        "name": "Foo",      
        "size": {
            "human": "832.73kB",
            "bytes": 852718
        },
        "date": {
            "human": "September 18, 2017",
            "epoch": 1505776741
        },
    }
},
{
    "bar": {
        "name": "bar",
        "size": {
            "human": "4.02MB",
            "bytes": 4212456
        },
        "date": {
            "human": "September 18, 2017",
            "epoch": 1505776741
        }
    }
}]
```

I'm using Newtonsoft's JSON.NET, and I can't seem to be able to create a data structure that would allow me to deserialize it, since it's the array of classes with different names.  Specifically the property names `"Foo"` and `"bar"` could differ at runtime.  Property names elsewhere in the JSON hierarchy are known.

Comment: Which names are liable to vary?  `"Foo"` and `"Bar"`?

Comment: Yes, that's right and nothing else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that only the names `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` are unknown at compile time, you can deserialize that JSON into a `List<Dictionary<string, RootObject>>`, where `RootObject` is a c# model I generated automatically using http://json2csharp.com/ from the JSON for the value of `"Foo"`.

Models:

```
public class Size
{
    public string human { get; set; }
    public int bytes { get; set; }
}

public class Date
{
    public string human { get; set; }
    public int epoch { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Size size { get; set; }
    public Date date { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization code:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, RootObject>>>(jsonString);
```

Notes:

- The outermost type must be an enumerable such `List<T>` since the outermost JSON container is an array -- a comma-separated sequence of values surrounded by `[` and `]`.  See [Serialization Guide: IEnumerable, Lists, and Arrays](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Lists).
- When a JSON object can have arbitrary property names but a fixed schema for property values, it can be deserialized to a `Dictionary<string, T>` for an appropriate `T`.  See [Deserialize a Dictionary](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm).
- Possibly `bytes` and `epoch` should be of type `long`.

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ggCmYz).

Comment: How silly of me, I've tried a Dictionary<string,RootObject>, but not a List<Dictionary<string,RootObject>>. You just saved the day!