# How do I deserialise json to c# that is valid json but doesn't follow a standard object pattern as it has no base parameter pair

Tags: json, json.net

I have the following JSON:

```
[{
    "theme-my-login": 
    {
        "latest_version":"6.4.7",
        "last_updated":"2017-01-06T18:14:00.000Z",
        "popular":true,
        "vulnerabilities":
        [
            {
                "id":6043,
                "title":"Theme My Login 6.3.9 - Local File Inclusion",
                "created_at":"2014-08-01T10:58:35.000Z",
                "updated_at":"2015-05-15T13:47:24.000Z",
                "published_date":null,
                "references":
                {
                    "url":["http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/127302/","http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2014/Jun/172","http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/68254/","https://security.dxw.com/advisories/lfi-in-theme-my-login/"]
                },
                "vuln_type":"LFI",
                "fixed_in":"6.3.10"
            }
        ]
    }
},{
    "other-item": 
    {
        "latest_version":"6.4.7",
        "last_updated":"2017-01-06T18:14:00.000Z",
        "popular":true,
        "vulnerabilities":
        [
            {
                "id":6043,
                "title":"Theme My Login 6.3.9 - Local File Inclusion",
                "created_at":"2014-08-01T10:58:35.000Z",
                "updated_at":"2015-05-15T13:47:24.000Z",
                "published_date":null,
                "references":
                {
                    "url":["http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/127302/","http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2014/Jun/172","http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/68254/","https://security.dxw.com/advisories/lfi-in-theme-my-login/"]
                },
                "vuln_type":"LFI",
                "fixed_in":"6.3.10"
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

json2csharp says the object model should look like this, but that's clearly not correct

```
public class References
{
    public List<string> url { get; set; }
}

public class Vulnerability
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
    public object published_date { get; set; }
    public References references { get; set; }
    public string vuln_type { get; set; }
    public string fixed_in { get; set; }
}

public class ThemeMyLogin
{
    public string latest_version { get; set; }
    public DateTime last_updated { get; set; }
    public bool popular { get; set; }
    public List<Vulnerability> vulnerabilities { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ThemeMyLogin __invalid_name__theme-my-login { get; set; }
}
```

that I am trying to deserialise into c# classes using Json.NET, but as the top level item doesn't have a traditional name:value pair (the name effectively is "theme-my-login" and the value is the object), it's not deserialising. 
Any pointers on how I can get this to deserialise? Do I need to use a custom deserialiser?

The reason I cannot use a dictionary as suggested in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24536533/how-can-i-parse-a-json-string-that-would-cause-illegal-c-sharp-identifiers) is that I need the value "theme-my-login" as one of the values in my model as it defines the object. I have added a second item into the json as this will be a list of items. I previously only included one to show the item structure.

Comment: Use `public Dictionary<string, ThemeMyLogin> LoginThemes { get; set; }` as shown in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536533/3744182).

Comment: I have amended the question to explain a few further points why the proposed solution will not work.

Comment: I think this is actually a duplicate then: [Deserializing a list of objects with different names in JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46355071/3744182).  That answer says to deserialize to a `List<Dictionary<string, ThemeMyLogin>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deserialize to `List<Dictionary<string, ThemeMyLogin>>` like so:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, ThemeMyLogin>>>(json);
```

The code-generation site http://json2csharp.com/ has some limitations of which you need to be aware:

1. The [JSON standard](http://json.org/) allows for two types of container:

   - The array, which is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).
   - The object, which is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace).

   If your root container is an array, http://json2csharp.com/ will auto-generate a `RootObject` model to deserialize each *object* in the array.  To actually deserialize the *entire array* you need to deserialize to a collection of root objects such as a `List<RootObject>`.  See *[Serialization Guide: IEnumerable, Lists, and Arrays](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Lists)*.
2. When a JSON property corresponds to an invalid c# identifier,  http://json2csharp.com/ will "helpfully" add a property to the containing type that looks like this:

   ```
   public PropertyType __invalid_name__my-invalid-identifier { get; set; }
   ```

   Of course this will not compile, so you need to notice any `__invalid_name` properties and manually fix the generated code.  Options for doing this include those covered in *[How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536533/3744182)* and elsewhere:

   - If the property name is fixed and known in advance, rename the c# property to something valid consistent with your coding conventions and mark it with [`[JsonProperty("my-invalid-identifier")]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute__ctor_1.htm).  (From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536739/3744182) by [ken2k](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536739/3744182)).
   - If the containing type consists entirely of variable property names with a fixed schema for their values corresponding to some type `T`, replace the containing type with a `Dictionary<string, T>`. (From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) by [L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b).)
   - If the containing object has a mixture of fixed and variable properties, see *[Deserialize json with known and unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15253875/3744182)* or *[How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40088941/3744182)*.

You seem to have encountered both limitations.  Working sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ngv64I).